# Paypal-Express payment error - incorrect ID

Tags: payment-methods, payment, paypal-express, multi-vendor, magento2.3.1

I'm using **Magento 2.3.1** with **Vnecoms multi-vendor** extension and I'm trying to pay with **PayPal-Express** - mode sale & sandbox.
I can log in in Paypal & it redirects me to the page to choose the shipment.

Arrived there exception.log & debug.log give me:

> main.CRITICAL: The "3000000008" order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID
>   and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): The
>   \"3000000008\" order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again. at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php:143)"} []

This doesn't happen in Authorization mode for some reason.

payment.log looks like this:

```
[2019-04-09 08:04:25] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'DoExpressCheckoutPayment' =>
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-1Y3185946J772174S',
    'PAYERID' => 'D2Q6ZYP2U59WA',
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '16.89',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
    'NOTIFYURL' => 'https://shop.2mazing.com/paypal/ipn/',
    'RETURNFMFDETAILS' => 1,
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.90',
    'ITEMAMT' => '15.99',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'Autositzauflage -Gray',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '15.99',
    'L_NUMBER1' => 'store_credit',
    'L_NAME1' => 'Shop-Guthaben',
    'L_QTY1' => 1,
    'L_AMT1' => '0.00',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'kauf@2mazing.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Simon Schmidt',
    'LASTNAME' => NULL,
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'DE',
    'STATE' => 'Empty',
    'CITY' => 'Freiburg',
    'STREET' => 'ESpachstr. 1',
    'ZIP' => '79111',
    'PHONENUM' => NULL,
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'DE',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'Empty',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'Freiburg',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'ESpachstr. 1',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '79111',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => NULL,
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'Simon Schmidt ',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
  ),
  'response' =>
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-1Y3185946J772174S',
    'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED' => 'false',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-04-09T08:04:25Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '23b2aead9b48f',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '52346509',
    'TRANSACTIONID' => '70R244159E137901D',
    'TRANSACTIONTYPE' => 'cart',
    'PAYMENTTYPE' => 'instant',
    'ORDERTIME' => '2019-04-09T08:04:24Z',
    'AMT' => '16.89',
    'FEEAMT' => '0.67',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
    'PAYMENTSTATUS' => 'Pending',
    'PENDINGREASON' => 'paymentreview',
    'REASONCODE' => 'None',
    'PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => 'Ineligible',
    'INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED' => 'false',
    'SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT' => 'false',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID' => '70R244159E137901D',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE' => 'cart',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE' => 'instant',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME' => '2019-04-09T08:04:24Z',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT' => '16.89',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT' => '0.67',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS' => 'Pending',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON' => 'paymentreview',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE' => 'None',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => 'Ineligible',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE' => 'None',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => 'merchant@2mazing.com',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID' => 'TCH52AZ5XS3HG',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => '0',
    'PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK' => 'Success',
  ),
) [] []
```

If I try to pay PHP gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer::format() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/vnecoms/module-vendors-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php
>   on line 148 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Renderer.php:51
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/vnecoms/module-vendors-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php(148):
>   Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer->format(NULL, 'html') #1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/vnecoms/module-vendors-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php(137):
>   Vnecoms\VendorsSales\Model\Order\Email\Sender->getFormattedShippingAddress(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/vendor/vnecoms/module-vendors-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php(82):
>
> Vnecoms\VendorsSales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender->prepareTemplate(Object(Vnecoms\VendorsSales\Model\Order))
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/vendor/vnecoms/module-vendors-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sen
>
> in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Renderer.php
>   on line 51

These errors are only occurring in Paypal Sale mode.

Also if I don't allow multiple payments per invoice ID in Paypal, I get the PayPal gateway rejected request - duplicate invoice issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar issue with that error message being generated on a multi store site - with a google search leading me here.

Our issue was that there must have been an error on the individual website creation - the installation didn't create various sequence tables in the database for a particular store view.

I found that the sequence_invoice_4, sequence_shipment_4 and sequence_creditmemo_4 (4 being the store code) tables were all missing plus the relevant lines in sales_sequence_meta and sales_sequence_profile tables.  Once created orders generated fine.

This could be a specific incident relevant to only our setup, but it could be worth checking just in case someone comes across this question.

This wouldn't happen in authorisation mode as the invoice (the first bit of the create order to generate) wouldn't be created until the payment was processed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after some hours debug and check files debug.log, exception.log, payment.log, I found the issue is

```
Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'sequence_value' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_invoice_1` () VALUES ()
```

Then I go to table sequence_invoice_1 and have changed type of "sequence_value" from int(10) to bigint(20). Now, it works fine.

Our customer have a lot order migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. That is an issue. Hope it can help someone.

Alothemes - Happy Coding!